# Simple chess engine in c language

Tags: c, chess

I'm looking for a chess engine that is written in C language and is between 500 to 2000 lines of code or its size to be a few kilo bytes. I don't need the engine to be super smart, just need a very basic chess engine.

Comment: I doubt very much one can write a chess engine in only 500 lines of code. Even if it exists, it won't be much more than "make a random move without any though".

Comment: This is definitely the site to ask this question. But since you are new, I make you aware of our sister site https://chess.stackexchange.com/ (which would be the wrong place to ask this question, but is still a very useful site to know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be seeking [Toledo Nanochess](http://www.nanochess.org/chess3.html).

> With only 1257 non-blank characters, Toledo Nanochess is the current world's smallest chess program in C language.