# Simple chess engine in C

Tags: c, chess

I need a chess library or simple chess engine code that is written in C that  allows me to play chess on Arduino Uno serial monitor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple chess engine in c language](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/53586/simple-chess-engine-in-c-language)

Answer (score 1):

As per my answer to this question (sometimes it's better to search before asking ;-)

You appear to be seeking [Toledo Nanochess](http://www.nanochess.org/chess3.html).

> With only 1257 non-blank characters, Toledo Nanochess is the current world's smallest chess program in C language.

Doing it over serial port is left as an exercise for the reader :-)